# Could Doyle have survived?

Tags: character, interstellar

I have been reading some *Interstellar* facts and came across one which caught my attention. It is not really a fact though - more like assumption. Here it is:

> Although Doyle is presumed drowned after being struck by the tidal
>   wave on Miller’s planet, his suit appears intact when the Ranger
>   leaves, meaning it is remotely possible *he could have survived* the
>   impact and is merely unconscious. Given the extreme time dilation on
>   Miller’s planet, a rescue is very possible. Assuming a mission were to
>   be dispatched from Cooper Station orbiting Saturn, it would take only
>   9 hours in relative time for Doyle to be rescued, but 65+ years would
>   have passed for the rest of the world. (assuming a dilation factor of
>   1 hour per 7 years).

I have always been sorry about Doyle's death. Mainly because his loss was necessary - he had plenty of time to get into the ranger before Amelia was brought back to the ranger by CASE.

I know it's just assumption, but does anybody have some further information about Doyle (from some interview maybe) and the possibility that he has survived or even was saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the start of the scene, a giant wave is moving away from them. But another one is coming towards them at the same time. That implies that the waves just keep coming, one after another. So even if Doyle has survived the first wave, another enormous wave would batter him again a few minutes after the first one, and then another wave shortly after that. If he wasn't dead initially, he would have been killed fairly soon.

Comment: Yes, i see. He would have to survive at least 9 waves (another came after cca. an hour in Interstellar, if i remember correctly) which seems pretty unlikely.